# Extracting fields from AWS S3 input paths in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-s3, logstash, logstash-grok

Is it possible to add fields/tags based on the bucket path? I tried to use grok but it didn't work.

Comment: i try to use match "path". I think there is no "path" in S3 inputs.

Comment: I've never used s3 before, but from the looks of the code, it doesn't look like it's included.  You'd need to modify the logstash s3 code to pass in the filename as path.

Comment: I mount s3 and go back to use the file input

[here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24617550/3757641)

Answer (score 0):

With Logstash 6.0.1, you will be able to get key (or path) for each file from S3.

Example:

```
input {
    s3 {
        bucket => "<bucket-name>"
        prefix => "<prefix>"
    }
}

filter {
    mutate {
        add_field => {
            "file" => "%{[@metadata][s3][key]}"
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

***Reference:*** [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24566122/logstash-how-to-use-filter-to-match-filename-when-using-s3/47816549#47816549)