# Logstash config - S3 Filenames?

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, logstash, elastic-stack

I'm attempting to use Logstash to collect sales data for multiple clients from multiple vendors.

So far i've an S3 (Inbox) bucket that I can drop my files (currently CSVs) into and according the client code prefix on the file, the data gets pushed into an Elastic index for each client. This all works nicely.

The problem I have is that I have data from multiple vendors and need a way of identifying which file is from which vendor. Adding an extra column to the CSV is not an option, so my plan was to add this to the filename, so i'd end up with a filenaming convention something like `clientcode_vendorcode_reportdate.csv`.

I may be missing something, but it seems that on S3 I can't get access to the filename inside my config, which seems crazy given that the prefix is clearly being read at some point. I was intending to use a Grok or Ruby filter to simply split the filename on the underscore, giving me three key variables that I can use in my config, but all attempts so far have failed. I can't even seem to get the full source_path or filename as a variable.

My config so far looks something like this - i've removed failed attempts at using Grok/Ruby filters.

```
input {
    s3 {
    access_key_id =>"MYACCESSKEYID"
    bucket => "sales-inbox"
    backup_to_bucket => "sales-archive"
    delete => "true"
    secret_access_key => "MYSECRETACCESSKEY"
        region => "eu-west-1"
        codec => plain
        prefix => "ABC"
        type => "ABC"
  }
    s3 {
    access_key_id =>"MYACCESSKEYID"
    bucket => "sales-inbox"
    backup_to_bucket => "sales-archive"
    delete => "true"
    secret_access_key => "MYSECRETACCESSKEY"
        region => "eu-west-1"
        codec => plain
        prefix => "DEF"
        type => "DEF"
  }
}

filter {
    if [type] == "ABC" {
        csv {
            columns => ["Date","Units","ProductID","Country"]
            separator => ","
        }
        mutate {
            add_field => { "client_code" => "abc" }
        }      
    } 
    else if [type] == "DEF" {
        csv {
            columns => ["Date","Units","ProductID","Country"]
            separator => ","
        }
        mutate {
            add_field => { "client_code" => "def" }
        }
    } 
    mutate
    {
        remove_field => [ "message" ]
    }   
}
output {
        elasticsearch {
            codec => json
            hosts => "myelasticcluster.com:9200"
            index => "sales_%{client_code}"
            document_type => "sale"
          }
        stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

An guidance from those well versed in Logstash configs would be much appreciated!

Comment: A similar question has been asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24566122/logstash-how-to-use-filter-to-match-filename-when-using-s3).

Comment: Thanks @Val, i'd seen that link before but missed the answer where someone says they've updated the plugin. Just trying to find out if this was merged into the official plugin and how I can access the path value.

Comment: You may also fork that plugin and re-package it, then maybe issue a PR.

Comment: Ok cool - i'll give that a go. Thanks again.

Comment: Cool, feel free to give an update here when you're done.

Comment: Ok, so I got this working! What I did; forked the S3 input plugin, copied the entire gist and then ran a git diff to see what had been changed. The gist with the solution is pretty behind the latest version of the S3 input plugin so I just noted the very small changes, manually amended my fork, pushed my changes, uninstalled the plugin, then reinstalled it - it's important that it's done like `bin/plugin install --no-verify` to pick up the forked version. You can see the key commit I made here: https://github.com/EssentialMusic/logstash-input-s3/commit/ee05d7b3a83a6000bac80980bbc5d2af1ab1e8ff

Comment: Awesome, thanks for sharing.

Comment: No problem, thanks for re-pointing me to that other question.